# My Jquery script crashed heroku app, works on localhost sails

Tags: jquery, heroku, sails.js, uglifyjs

I have an app i created with sailsjs on my computer.
When tring to upload it to the heroku server I get errors related to uglifying (production.js).
these are from the papertrail addon : link to the papertrail: https://papertrailapp.com/systems/friendlinew/events?r=661978136430596096-661995019569549312

> > Uglifying source .tmp/public/concat/production.js failed. 
> >       Warning: Uglification failed. 
> >       Unexpected token: operator (>).
> >       Line 21196 in .tmp/public/concat/production.js

```
Aborted due to warnings. 
Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task 
JS_Parse_Error { 
message: 'Unexpected token: operator (>)', 
filename: '../concat/production.js', 
line: 21196, 
col: 22, 
pos: 1312332,
```

stack: 'Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at  (/app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), :1526:18)\n    at js_error (eval at  (/app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), :1534:11)\n    at croak (eval at  (/app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), :2026:9)\n    at token_error (eval at  (/app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), :2034:9)\n    at unexpected (eval at  (/app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), :2040:9)\n    at expr_atom (eval at  (/app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), :2554:9)\n    at maybe_unary (eval at  (/app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), :2716:19)\n    at expr_ops (eval at  (/app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), :2751:24)\n    at maybe_conditional (eval at  (/app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), :2756:20)\n    at maybe_assign (eval at  (/app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), :2780:20)' }

The script works fine when I run it on my localhost.
my code:

```
function makeProgressLine(id,percent) {     
 itemz = document.getElementById(id);
 var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(itemz, {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: {width: '100%', height: '100%'},
  text: {
    style: {
      // Text color.
      // Default: same as stroke color (options.color)
      color: '#999',
      position: 'absolute',
      right: '0',
      top: '30px',
      padding: 0,
      margin: 0,
      transform: null
    },
    autoStyleContainer: false
  },
  from: {color: '#00ff00'},
  to: {color: '#ED6A5A'},
  step: (state, bar) => {
      bar.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
      bar.setText(Math.round(bar.value() * 100) + ' %');
  }
});

bar.animate(percent);
}   

function makeProgressCircle(id,percent) {     
    itemz = document.getElementById(id);
    var day = new ProgressBar.Circle(itemz, {
    color: '#aaa',
    // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
    // prevent clipping
    strokeWidth: 4,
    trailWidth: 1,
    easing: 'easeInOut',
    duration: 1400,
    text: {
        autoStyleContainer: false
    },
    from: { color: '#f0f', width: 1 },
    to: { color: '#333', width: 4 },
    // Set default step function for all animate calls
    step: function(state, circle) {
        circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
        circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

        var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
        if (value === 0) {
        circle.setText('');
        } else {
        circle.setText(value);
        console.log(value);
        }

    }
    });
//day.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
//day.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';

day.animate(percent);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
}

$(document).ready(function () { 
    makeProgressCircle('container',0.8);
    for (i=1;i<6;i++) {
       makeProgressLine('progress' + i,i*0.2); 
    }


});
```

Comment: and those errors are...?

Comment: edited, I hope it helps... I am kind of lost as I am not sure what errors relate to this exactly and why..